# greenplum hadoop in greenplum how to configure to generate gphdfs.so

Tags: hadoop, greenplum

in  greenplum  how to configure  to  generate  gphdfs.so?
when I

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE csv_hdfs_lineitem (like a) LOCATION ( 'gphdfs://xxxxx/gptest/lineitem.csv' ) FORMAT 'text' (delimiter E'|' null E'\N' escape E'off' fill missing fields) ENCODING 'UTF8' ;
```

it shows

> ERROR: protocol "gphdfs" does not exist

Comment: does 'ls gphdfs://xxxxx/gptest/lineitem.csv' work in shell?..

Comment: because   it lack of gphdfs.sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: protocol "gphdfs" does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156655/error-protocol-gphdfs-does-not-exist)

Comment: `dfs -ls hdfs://xxxxx/gptest/lineitem.csv` - works?

Comment: it  works   , it has nothing with hdfs

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a SQL Script included in Greenplum Package. You will find the same script in `$GPHOME/share/postgresql/cdb_external_extensions.sql`

Run this:

`psql -f $GPHOME/share/postgresql/cdb_external_extensions.sql`

Hope this helps..